# Change distance between boxplots in the same figure in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to change the distance between two boxplots in one figure. I use pyplot for python for drawing them.

example code:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np            

data = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

figure()

bp = boxplot(data)
show()
```

unfortunately the boxplots are very far a way from each other, how can I change this?

Comment: This is an artifact of the way that matplotlib sets up the limits.  See the answers at the linked question.